# How to read A column in xlsx file with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I know how to read a column with a certain header, but what if I want to read the whole column that doesn't have a header, like A?

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel('base.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(excel_data["A"])
```

It doesn't work

Comment: `usecols=[0]` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can view all the columns with:

```
excel_data.head()
```

Comment: I need only certain info inside 'A1' column, is it possible to extract with pandas? I did it with openpyxl

Comment: You need to give more information. Are we filtering the list?